# Checkbox with image and overlayed image on checked state

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I need help for checkbox using CSS only.

First of all it function correctly. However, I want to overlay the checked image on top of the unchecked image when the button is clicked. How to achieve this?

```css
.frm_checkbox {border: 1px solid red;}

.frm_checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {display: none; }

input#field_32gyuu-0 {
 background: url('http://www.uswebcompany.com/plugins/formidable/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/christmasLights.png') 0 0px no-repeat;
    z-index: 10;
 content: "";
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 12px;
 height: 75px;
 width: 75px;
 line-height: 16px;
 margin: -2px 6px 0 0;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#frm_checkbox_112-0 input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
 background: url('http://www.uswebcompany.com/plugins/formidable/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/lightbox-checkmark.png') 0 0px no-repeat;
 height: 75px;
 width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="frm_field_162_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  form-group frm_top_container">
    <label  class="frm_primary_label control-label">Checkboxes
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="frm_opt_container">
        <div class="frm_checkbox checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_162-0">
            <label for="field_32gyuu-0">
                <input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[162][]" id="field_32gyuu-0" value="Option 1"  /> Option 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="frm_checkbox checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_162-1">
            <label for="field_32gyuu-1">
                <input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[162][]" id="field_32gyuu-1" value="Option 2"  /> Option 2</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It isn't working here. Try with a jsfiddle or jsbin.

Comment: Sir it is working as far as the checkbox.  However, I'm trying to remove the checkbox and put image instead and make it clickable with a over layed check mark.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to wrap the label text in a `span`, but take a look at the code below. I wasn't sure if you still wanted to see the checkbox, so toggle `display: none` as required.

```css
.checkbox label {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.checkbox label > span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.checkbox label > span:before {
  content: url("http://www.uswebcompany.com/plugins/formidable/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/christmasLights.png");
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 31px;
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:before {
  content: url("http://www.uswebcompany.com/plugins/formidable/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/lightbox-checkmark.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="frm_field_162_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  form-group frm_top_container">
  <label class="frm_primary_label control-label">Checkboxes
    <span class="frm_required"></span>
  </label>
  <div class="frm_opt_container">
    <div class="frm_checkbox checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_162-0">
      <label for="field_32gyuu-0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[162][]" id="field_32gyuu-0" value="Option 1" /> <span>Option 1</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="frm_checkbox checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_162-1">
      <label for="field_32gyuu-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[162][]" id="field_32gyuu-1" value="Option 2" /> <span>Option 2</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with the original code and by id?  Beacuse i/m using formidable pro and the code is auto generated. (i.e.) without adding the span.

Comment: Off the top of my head - I don't think so, you can't use `::before` or `::after` on input elements or navigate up with CSS. Is adding the `span` with JavaScript practical?